# Why quantile function in python result is NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

I use the following code:

```
# Import Pandas
import pandas as pd

# Load Movies Metadata
metadata = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/jiyeon1997/movie-recommender-python/raw/4c8c3a1fd0a7b163cc53b1972de26d94b833f993/movies_metadata.csv', low_memory=False)

# Print the first three rows
metadata.head(3)
```

I would like to calculate the 90% quantile:

```
m = metadata['vote_count'].quantile(0.90)
print(m)
Result: nan
```

However, if I use the following code, I get the required result:

```
qun =  np.nanpercentile(metadata['vote_count'], 90, axis=0)
print (qun)
```

Why is it? Can I use the `quantile` function so I get the required result?

Comment: Waht is your pandas version? I got for both 160.0

Comment: I also get 160.0 like @jezrael

Comment: my panda's version: pandas: 0.18.1

Comment: It is really old, please upgrade, then error is gone

Comment: Thx @jezrael, It works after the upgrade, the second option that worked before does not work anymore.